# How to insert image into folder in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I create a new folder into public folder by `laravel` codes that is:

```
$f1=Input::get('f1');
$path ='img/uploads/'.$f1;
File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
```

Then I select that folder to web page using this code in blade.php

```
{{ Form::select('f1', $list, null,array('class' => 'form-control' ,'list')) }}` and controller.php ` $list = File::directories('img/uploads/');
return View::make('gallery.addnewgallery',array('list'=>$list));
```

Then, I'm trying to insert a image to that selected folder and also database using controller.php code is here:

```
$f1=Input::get('f1');
$path ='img/uploads/'.$f1;
$file=File::directories($f1, '=', $path);      
Log::info($file );
$file=Input::file('galimg');
$filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move('img/uploads/'.$f1,$filename); 
ForumGallery::create([
    'galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
    'galimg'=>$f1.'/'.$filename
]);
```

My problem is when in select a folder and enter a image using browse, I got an error `InvalidArgumentException`. The `1` directory does not exist (I select folder `2` from dropdown box).

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML Output from Browser of your code

```
<select name="f1"><option value="0">1</option><option value="1">2</option><option value="2">3</option><option value="3">4</option><option value="4">5</option><option value="5">6</option></select>
```

so when you are select option 2 it's value would be 1 so it throws **InvalidArgumentException**

So you have to write like following :
So that it will display value and it's content same (For you it's folder name)

```
<select>
     <option selected disabled>Please select one option</option>
     @foreach($folders as $folder)
     <option value="{{ $folder }}">{{ $folder }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```